# jars required to be added to use rich notify messages in jsf?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, notify

i am using rich notify messages and added all related jars namely 
**richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final** , 
**richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final**, 
**standard-1.1.2** ,
**jstl-1.2** ,
**validation-api-1.0.0.GA** ,
**richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final** ,
**richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final**
**jsf-impl-2.0.2**, 
**cssparser-0.9.5**, 
**guava-r08**, 
**jhighlight-1.0.** 
but i am getting class not found exception:org.richfaces.component.NotifyAttributes.

sample.xhtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Validation Form" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <rich:validator event="change">
                        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
                        <h:inputText label="Name" id="name" value="#{userBean.name}"
                            required="true">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message for="name" ajaxRendered="true" />
                        <h:outputText value="Job:" />
                        <h:inputText label="Job" id="job" value="#{userBean.job}"
                            requiredMessage="Job is required">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="50" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message for="job" ajaxRendered="true" />
                        <h:outputText value="Address:" />
                        <h:inputText label="Address" id="address"
                            value="#{userBean.address}" requiredMessage="Address is required">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="10" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message for="address" ajaxRendered="true" />
                        <h:outputText value="Zip:" />
                        <h:inputText label="Zip" id="zip" value="#{userBean.zip}"
                            requiredMessage="Zip is required">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="9" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <rich:message for="zip" ajaxRendered="true" />
                    </rich:validator>
                    <rich:notifyMessages stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true" escape="false"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Ajax Validate" />
                    </f:facet>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </rich:panel>
    </ui:composition>

 bean class used to set and get bean vlaues.let me know whats wrong with existing code ,along with jars to be added   
    userBean.java:

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class userBean {
        private String name;
        private String job;
        private String address;
        private String zip;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getJob() {
            return job;
        }
        public void setJob(String job) {
            this.job = job;
        }
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public String getZip() {
            return zip;
        }
        public void setZip(String zip) {
            this.zip = zip;
        }

    }



 error:
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.richfaces.component.NotifyAttributes
```

i am not getting why this is getting although i added all required jars of richfaces4.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

`notify` component is not part of RichFaces 4.0. See [Richfaces 4.0 VDL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/vdldoc/). You have to use version 4.1 or up (for example current version RichFaces 4.3).
Note: all richfaces-???.jar(s) should be for **the same version** of RichFaces.