# No tag "notifyMessage" defined in tag library imported with prefix "rich"

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm busy getting this red-line when trying to use `<rich:notifyMessage>`. I'm used to primefaces but for this project richfaces is inevitable, hence i'm quite a novice here. I'm using `richfaces 3.3.4 final` and all required jars are included. What could I be missing? Is there a perfect alternative for a notification message pop-up apart from `<rich:message>` or `<rich:messages>`? I'd really appreciate a working example too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if this component is available in RichFaces 3.3.4 (it might have ben introduced in a newer version). And a simple googling resulted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300900/jars-required-to-be-added-to-use-rich-notify-messages-in-jsf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jars required to be added to use rich notify messages in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300900/jars-required-to-be-added-to-use-rich-notify-messages-in-jsf)

Comment: Thanks much, let me try the upgrade. Apologies for not bumping into this :-)